# Dependency of database fields

Tags: php, database, oop, smarty

I currently have this method:

```
public function getUser($id) {
    $user = $this->db->getSingleRecord("SELECT user_id,  user_login, user_email FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", $id);

    return $user;
}
```

I think it's pretty obvious what this does. $user is an associative array, so $user['user_id'], $user['user_login'] and $user['user_email'] will exist. This will be passed to a Smarty template and in that file, these keys will be used:

```
login: {$user['user_login']|escape} <br />
```

This made me wondering... is this fine? If the database field changes, I would need to edit 2 files now. I could change the method to something like this:

```
public function getUser($id) {
    $user = $this->db->getSingleRecord("SELECT user_id,  user_login, user_email FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", $id);

    if (empty($user))
      // return empty array
      return $user;
    else
      return array('user_id' => $user['user_id'], 'user_login' => $user['user_login'], 'user_email' => $user['user_email']);
}
```

If the database field changes, I would only need to edit one file (this method) now. My first thought is that this approach is much better.

On the other hand, should you really take care of these things? Normally, you don't change these fields.

What is the best approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the correspondence of database fields and `$user` structure required by the template a coincidence. Use the one you currently use. If the database schema changes, switch to the alternative one (you will have to modify the method anyway, to change the query).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't really get it. Why should I consider it a coincidence and why should I switch to the second method when the database schema changes (and not now)? Thanks

Comment: For the moment, both functions do exactly the same. So use the simpler one. When the database schema changes, you have two options: (1) Change only the query. This will break the contract that the function has with it's environment (e.g. with the template, because the template expects certain entries in the returned array). (2) Keep the contract. For this you have to map the results of the new query to array entries that the contract demands (like you did in your alternative approach).